# Render text as template tag in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

So i am trying to create a dynamic side bar. Here is the content on 1 of the side bar. This is widget.content coming from database. Using generic.DetailView

```
<div class="widget">
     <img src="{% static 'frontend/images/banner2.png' %}"  alt=""/>
 </div>
```

And i created a template tag to render the string.

```
@register.assignment_tag(takes_context=True)
def enquiry_form(context):
    return EnquiryForm()

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def render_as_template(context, template_as_string):
   template_as_object = context.template.engine.from_string(template_as_string)
   return template_as_object.render(context)
```

In my page.html i am calling

```
{% render_as_template widget.content|safe %}
```

But i am getting

```
 Invalid block tag: 'static'
```

Is there any work around for this. Also i have enquiry_form in one of the sidebar. Any Solution? I am using Django 1.8

Answer (score 0):

Okay i got the answer. When ever i save widget in database i must save load static

> Before

```
<div class="widget">
   <img src="{% static 'frontend/images/banner2.png' %}"  alt=""/>
</div>
```

> After

```
{% load static %}
{% load templatetags %}  # if needed
<div class="widget">
   <img src="{% static 'frontend/images/banner2.png' %}"  alt=""/>
</div>
```