# How do I render image, title and link to template from views using one 'for loop'

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm scraping http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-1.html and I want to return the **image**, **title**, **rating** and **price** of the first 10 books in a bootstrap card. The code below returns only the title. My focus is on rendering the image, title, and link in one `for` loop

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


r = requests.get("http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-1.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')

book = soup.findAll('h3')


book_list = []

for title in book [:10]:
    book_list.append(title.text)


def index(req):
    return render(req, 'books/index.html', {'book_list': book_list})
```

This is the bootstrap card.

```html
{% for title in book_list %}
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="{{image}}" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-text">{{title}}.</h5>
            <p class="card-text">{{rating}}.</p>
            <h5 class="card-text">{{price}}.</h5>
            <a href="url"><h6>{{link}} </h6></a>
        </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

How can I render all the metadata of the books in a single `for` loop as seen in the HTML template? I'm targeting the card with class name "product_pod" and extract the details.

Answer (score 1):

This should help you:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


r = requests.get("http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-1.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')

li_tags = soup.find_all('li', class_ = "col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3")[:10]

for li in li_tags:

    print('-'*100)
    
    img = "http://books.toscrape.com/"+ li.article.div.a.img['src'][2:]
    print(f"Image link = {img}")

    title = li.article.h3.a['title']
    print(f"Title = {title}")

    rating = li.article.p['class'][-1]
    print(f"Rating = {rating} Star(s)")

    price = li.article.find('div', class_ = "product_price").p.text
    print(f"Price = {price}")
```

Output:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Image link = http://books.toscrape.com//media/cache/2c/da/2cdad67c44b002e7ead0cc35693c0e8b.jpg
Title = A Light in the Attic
Rating = Three Star(s)
Price = £51.77
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Image link = http://books.toscrape.com//media/cache/26/0c/260c6ae16bce31c8f8c95daddd9f4a1c.jpg
Title = Tipping the Velvet
Rating = One Star(s)
Price = £53.74
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Image link = http://books.toscrape.com//media/cache/3e/ef/3eef99c9d9adef34639f510662022830.jpg
Title = Soumission
Rating = One Star(s)
Price = £50.10
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Image link = http://books.toscrape.com//media/cache/32/51/3251cf3a3412f53f339e42cac2134093.jpg
Title = Sharp Objects
Rating = Four Star(s)
Price = £47.82
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Image link = http://books.toscrape.com//media/cache/be/a5/bea5697f2534a2f86a3ef27b5a8c12a6.jpg
Title = Sapiens: A Brief History of Humankind
Rating = Five Star(s)
Price = £54.23
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Image link = http://books.toscrape.com//media/cache/68/33/68339b4c9bc034267e1da611ab3b34f8.jpg
Title = The Requiem Red
Rating = One Star(s)
Price = £22.65
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Image link = http://books.toscrape.com//media/cache/92/27/92274a95b7c251fea59a2b8a78275ab4.jpg
Title = The Dirty Little Secrets of Getting Your Dream Job
Rating = Four Star(s)
Price = £33.34
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Image link = http://books.toscrape.com//media/cache/3d/54/3d54940e57e662c4dd1f3ff00c78cc64.jpg
Title = The Coming Woman: A Novel Based on the Life of the Infamous Feminist, Victoria Woodhull
Rating = Three Star(s)
Price = £17.93
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Image link = http://books.toscrape.com//media/cache/66/88/66883b91f6804b2323c8369331cb7dd1.jpg
Title = The Boys in the Boat: Nine Americans and Their Epic Quest for Gold at the 1936 Berlin Olympics
Rating = Four Star(s)
Price = £22.60
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Image link = http://books.toscrape.com//media/cache/58/46/5846057e28022268153beff6d352b06c.jpg
Title = The Black Maria
Rating = One Star(s)
Price = £52.15
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. How can I render this in the template I have shown in the original question? I had managed to append the title in the original question

Comment: Oh...I don't think that I will be able to help you, cuz I haven't worked with Django. Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31214934/render-text-as-template-tag-in-django

Comment: I've checked the question and it doesn't involve the 'for loop' as I need. Thanks for the concern though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip()` builtin method to get all required parameters together. For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-1.html'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

for image, title, rating, price in list(zip(soup.select('article .thumbnail'),
                                       soup.select('article h3 a'),
                                       soup.select('article .star-rating'),
                                       soup.select('article .price_color')))[:10]:

    print(image['src'].replace('..','http://books.toscrape.com'))
    print(title['title'])
    print(rating['class'][-1])
    print(price.text)

    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
A Light in the Attic
Three
£51.77
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
http://books.toscrape.com/media/cache/26/0c/260c6ae16bce31c8f8c95daddd9f4a1c.jpg
Tipping the Velvet
One
£53.74
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
http://books.toscrape.com/media/cache/3e/ef/3eef99c9d9adef34639f510662022830.jpg
Soumission
One
£50.10
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
http://books.toscrape.com/media/cache/32/51/3251cf3a3412f53f339e42cac2134093.jpg
Sharp Objects
Four
£47.82
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
http://books.toscrape.com/media/cache/be/a5/bea5697f2534a2f86a3ef27b5a8c12a6.jpg
Sapiens: A Brief History of Humankind
Five
£54.23
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
http://books.toscrape.com/media/cache/68/33/68339b4c9bc034267e1da611ab3b34f8.jpg
The Requiem Red
One
£22.65
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
http://books.toscrape.com/media/cache/92/27/92274a95b7c251fea59a2b8a78275ab4.jpg
The Dirty Little Secrets of Getting Your Dream Job
Four
£33.34
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
http://books.toscrape.com/media/cache/3d/54/3d54940e57e662c4dd1f3ff00c78cc64.jpg
The Coming Woman: A Novel Based on the Life of the Infamous Feminist, Victoria Woodhull
Three
£17.93
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
http://books.toscrape.com/media/cache/66/88/66883b91f6804b2323c8369331cb7dd1.jpg
The Boys in the Boat: Nine Americans and Their Epic Quest for Gold at the 1936 Berlin Olympics
Four
£22.60
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
http://books.toscrape.com/media/cache/58/46/5846057e28022268153beff6d352b06c.jpg
The Black Maria
One
£52.15
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thank you for this. The code is running perfectly. However, my biggest issue is how to render the details in a Django template (bootstrap card as shown in the original question). Directly from views to the template, say using the append method.

Answer (score 0):

```
# views.py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get("http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-1.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')

book = soup.findAll('h3')

book_list = []

for image, title, rating, price in list(zip(soup.select('article .thumbnail'),
                                       soup.select('article h3 a'),
                                       soup.select('article .star-rating'),
                                       soup.select('article .price_color')))[:10]:

    book = {"image": image['src'].replace('..','http://books.toscrape.com') ,"title": title['title'], "rating":rating['class'][-1], "price": price.text}
    book_list.append(book)

def index(req):
    return render(req, 'books/index.html', {'book_list': book_list})
```

Then on template

```
{% for book in book_list %}
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ book.image }}" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-text">{{book.title}}.</h5>
        <p class="card-text">{{book.rating}}.</p>
        <h5 class="card-text">{{book.price}}.</h5>
        <a href="url">
            <h6>{{book.link}} </h6>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This works, thank you so much. Somehow I can't make the ``{{book.link}} ``work. I want it to take me to the book in  http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-1.html

Comment: Replace value of href ```url``` with ```{{ book.link}} ```